# Android Pjsip conference app

Tags: android, pjsip, conference

Im working on the [sip](http://www.pjsip.org/) android app. I cant find any good code for make **conferance**. Can someone help me?

Thanks..

Comment: If you have you implemented conference call. please let me know.

Comment: @vinay did you get solution bro

Comment: @Can Shain did you implement it bro??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you referred open source project CSipSimple. which supports conference feature. Note that CsipSimple uses [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) sip stack library.

Here is the link for that

https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/

Comment: Did u implemented pjsip call transferring and conferencing with audio recording?

Comment: Actually, I worked on this project long ago. I am not sure about the call transferring but yeah conferencing feature was there.